# Show div (preloader) only once - until cache/session is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a preloader on a landing page I've created (normally against this type of thing buy hay-ho). The preloader works fine, it displays, animates for a second then fades out displaying the website.

What I'd like to achieve is to show this only once, when the user first visits the page and then never again until they clear their cache or at least for a lengthly timescale. To do this I'm trying to use jquery-cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) - but I just can't get it to work, it still displays every time I refresh the page. The mark-up/script I'm using is below...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="preloader">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**Original JS (displays everytime page is visited):**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preloader').delay(1200).fadeOut(800,function(){$(this).remove();});
    });
});
```

**New JS (not working) attempting to use a cookie:**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie('noPreloader')) $('#preloader').hide();
        else {
            $(window).load(function(){
            $('#preloader').delay(1200).fadeOut(800,function(){$(this).remove();});
        });
    }
});
```

I'd greatly appreciate if someone would shed some light on this as I'm a bit stuck!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see where you create a cookie for your check. It suppose to be something like this:

```
if (!$.cookie('noPreloader')) {
  // show your preloader
  ...
  // and now we create 1 year cookie
  $.cookie('noPreloader', true, {path: '/', expire: 365});
}
```

Please note - in my example your block suppose to be hidden on load. You show it afterwards(since you want to show it only 1st time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your right I'm definitely missing something but I still can't get it to work :s

Comment: Based on my answer - you need to make your element hidden (display: none; will suffice). In the if you need to show your element.  Kind of like this - $('#preloader').show(); After that you need to add your function with fadeout

Comment: Thanks a lot,! I've got it working now - I'll post my code below for reference. Hopefully it comes in handy for someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help UtherTG! Here is my final script for anyone else who is trying to achieve something similar...

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($.cookie('noPreloader'))
    {
        $('#preloader').hide();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#preloader').delay(1200).fadeOut(800,function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

        // and now we create 1 year cookie
        $.cookie('noPreloader', true, {path: '/', expire: 365});
    }
});
```